# gcc inline asm x86 CPU flags as input dependency

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, constraints

I want to create a function for addition two 16-bit integers with overflow detection. I have generic variant written in portable c. But the generic variant is not optimal for x86 target, because CPU internally calculate overflow flag when execute ADD/SUB/etc. Of course, there is`__builtin_add_overflow()`, but in my case it generates some boilerplate.
So I write the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct result_t
{
    uint16_t src;
    uint16_t dst;
    uint8_t  of;
};

static void add_u16_with_overflow(result_t& r)
{
    char of, cf;
    asm (
        " addw %[dst], %[src] " 
        : [dst] "+mr"(r.dst)//, "=@cco"(of), "=@ccc"(cf)
        : [src] "imr" (r.src) 
        : "cc"
        );

    asm (" seto %0 " : "=rm" (r.of) );

}

uint16_t test_add(uint16_t a, uint16_t b)
{
    result_t r;
    r.src = a;
    r.dst = b;
    add_u16_with_overflow(r);
    add_u16_with_overflow(r);

    return (r.dst + r.of); // use r.dst and r.of for prevent discarding
}
```

I've played with https://godbolt.org/g/2mLF55 (gcc 7.2 -O2 -std=c++11) and it results

```
test_add(unsigned short, unsigned short):
  seto %al 
  movzbl %al, %eax
  addw %si, %di 
  addw %si, %di 
  addl %esi, %eax
  ret
```

So, `seto %0` is reordered. It seems gcc think there is no dependency between two consequent `asm()` statements. And "cc" clobber doesn't have any effect for flags dependency.

I can't use `volatile` because `seto %0` or whole function can be (and have to) optimized out if result (or some part of result) is not used.

I can add dependency for r.dst: `asm (" seto %0 " : "=rm" (r.of) : "rm"(r.dst) );`, and reordering will not happen. But it is not a "right thing", and compiler still can insert some code changes flags (but not changes r.dst) between `add` and `seto` statement.

Is there way to say "this asm() statement change some cpu flags" and "this asm() use some cpu flags" for dependency between statement and prevent reordering?

Comment: I haven't looked at your full question but since you are using GCC 7.x you can use the `=%cc` constraint to get access to a specific flag. In your case `=%cco`. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html  . Otherwise you can place the `seto` inside the first extended asm statement with an appropriate output constraint.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, GCC 7.x is for example (it is default at godbolt.org), 5.x and 6.x is my target also. So I can't use `=%cco`.If I add `seto` in first asm statement it will not be discarded when 'overflow' is not used, resulting bigger code and worse performance (my target is maximize performance).

Comment: One other observation. In AT&T syntax src is first and destination is second (this is reverse of Intel syntax).

Comment: One could argue that the overflow checking is always appropriate.  You're thinking in terms of the first 16bit overflowing into the second.  But the second 16bit value could (conceivably) overflow as well. Failing to check for obvious error conditions is usually a bad idea.  Whatever perf you save tends to be lost when things sometimes crash.  Also, you might want to use `"qm"` for the overflow rather than `rm`.  Even with 7.x, there's no way to have flags as an input constraint. I'd look again at `__builtin_add_overflow` and make sure you're building with optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at gcc's output for `__builtin_add_overflow`, but how bad is it?  [@David's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020613/gcc-inline-asm-x86-cpu-flags-as-input-dependency/48027994#comment83018661_48020613) suggestion to use it, and https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm is usually good, especially if you're worried about how this will optimize.  `asm` defeats constant propagation and some other things.

Also, if you are going to use ASM, note that [att](/questions/tagged/att) syntax is `add %[src], %[dst]` operand order.  See [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) for details, unless you're always going to build your code with `-masm=intel`.

> Is there way to say "this asm() statement change some cpu flags" and "this asm() use some cpu flags" for dependency between statement and prevent reordering?

No.  **Put the flag-consuming instruction (`seto`) inside the same `asm` block as the flag-producing instruction**.  An `asm` statement can have an many input and output operands as you like, limited only by register-allocation difficulty (but multiple memory outputs can use the same base register with different offsets).  Anyway, an extra write-only output on the statement containing the `add` isn't going to cause any inefficiency.

I was going to suggest that if you want multiple flag outputs from one instruction, use LAHF to Load AH from FLAGS.  But that doesn't include OF, only the other condition codes.  This is often inconvenient and seems like a bad design choice because there are [some unused reserved bits in the low 8 of EFLAGS/RFLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register), so OF could have been in the low 8 along with CF, SF, ZF, PF, and AF.  But since that isn't the case, `setc` + `seto` are probably better than `pushf` / reload, but that is worth considering.

---

Even if there was syntax for flag-input (like there is for flag-output), there would be *very* little to gain from letting gcc insert some of its own non-flag-modifying instructions (like `lea` or `mov`) between your two separate `asm` statements.

You don't want them reordered or anything, so putting them in the same asm statement makes by far the most sense.  Even on an in-order CPU, `add` is low latency so it's not a big bottleneck to put a dependent instruction right after it.

---

And BTW, a `jcc` might be more efficient if overflow is an error condition that doesn't happen normally.  But unfortunately GNU C `asm goto` doesn't support output operands.  You could take a pointer input and modify `dst` in memory (and use a `"memory"` clobber), but forcing a store/reload sucks more than using `setc` or `seto` to produce an input for a compiler-generated `test`/`jnz`.

If you didn't also need an output, you could put C labels on a `return true` and a `return false` statement, which (after inlining) would turn your code into a jcc to wherever the compiler wanted to lay out the branches of an `if()`.  e.g. see how Linux does it: (with extra complicating factors in these two examples I found): [setting up to patch the code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h#L146) after checking a CPU feature once at boot, or something with a section for a jump table in [`arch_static_branch`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/jump_label.h#L34).)